# Computer can't recognise svgz file

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have CS5 and CS6 and Adobe Reader etc on my computer. Why can't my computer recognise and open an svgz file?

Comment: Try open it with your web browser.

Answer (score 1):

"SVGz" is a compressed file format that uses *gzip* (an open source project) so if you deflate it with software (like gzip) you should have the uncompressed SVG.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gzip

Some (most?) servers actually serve SVG (and other formats) as compressed with gzip, but they do it on the fly and it is transparent for users on both the server and client sides. This means that virtually all browsers can open SVGZ **provided the proper headers are sent**. This may be difficult if you are merely opening a locally stored compressed SVGZ file and have no way to send a proper HTTP header.